# Запуск демона в контейнере при помощи sysv скрипта

Tags: linux, bash, docker

столкнулся с такой проблемой, есть ПО, состоящее из 3 неразрывных бинарников и библиотек, которые надо запустить, при этом они расчитаны под systemd, тобишь запускают друг друга из своего интерфейса (у них просто написано там systemctl start pw-manager). Запаковать в контейнер и просто исполнить каждый в тихом режиме получается, но хочется написать скрипты в /etc/init.d, чтобы прописать (service pwmanager start).
При таком запуске всё хорошо.

```
 cd  /opt/percoweb/manager
    ./pw-manager 1>>/dev/null 2>>/dev/nul &
        echo "pwmanager server started"
```

Но при попытке череp start-stop-daemon ловлю ошибку

```
root@ba2c10b87d19:/opt/percoweb/manager# start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile /var/run/pw-manager.pid --exec /opt/percoweb/manager/pw-manager
panic: Create config err

goroutine 1 [running]:
_/C_/Users/vdm/WebStormProjects/pw-manager-light/golib.ReadConfig()
        C:/Users/vdm/WebStormProjects/pw-manager-light/golib/fs.go:302 +0x3b6
_/C_/Users/vdm/WebStormProjects/pw-manager-light/golib.init()
        C:/Users/vdm/WebStormProjects/pw-manager-light/golib/auth.go:19 +0x2e
```

Вообще при попытке запуска этих файлов будучи не находясь в директории с ними ловлю ошибку. Думаю я плохо знаю линукс и тут выход будет простой, просто я чего-то не знаю.